# RegEx is matching characters before I want it to

Tags: regex

I need to parse a string that looks like this: `A Christmas Special - Special of the day` into 3 or 4 distinctive groups depending on if the `-` character is present in the original string or not like such:

(A Christmas Special) ( - ) (Special) (of the day) if the  - char was present.

or

(A Christmas Special) (Special) (of the day) if the - char was not present.

The RegEx pattern that I am trying to use on the string looks like this: `^(.+?)( - )?(Special)(.*)`

Which translates to:

Group1 = Matches any character (except newline) Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]

Group2 = Matches `-` literally. Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

Group3: Matches the characters `Special` literally

Group4:  Matches any character (except newline) Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

The problem with the expression as it stands now is that because the `-` character is optional, the first occurrence of the word `Special` gets treated like it's part of a different group than I want it to be a part of so the resulting groups look like this.

(A Christmas) (Special) ( - Special of the day)  if the - char was present.

or

(A Christmas) (Special) (Special of the day) if the - char was not present.

Which does not match either of the grouping patterns that I am trying to get from the string so the question is obvious, which is.

How do I alter the regex pattern so it does not treat the first occurrence of the word Special as it's own unique group, but instead make the 2nd occurrence unique so I can get the grouping that I was expecting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
^([^-]+[^-\s])\s?( - )?(Special)\s?(.*)
```

`([^-]+[^-\s])` : Matches any string that doesn't contain '-' nor finalize in whitespace.

`\s?( - )?` : Matches a whitespace or ' - '

`(Special)\s?(.*)` : Matches 'Special + *whitespace* (optional) + any_string'

Comment: I am not sure who down voted your comment, but it seems to work fine and is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is greedy by default, and stops at the first match.  To make the match lazy, you can use a ? character after the search term.  For example,

[.+] is greedy, but [.+?] is lazy.

This website is a fantastic repository of regular expression information.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but please read my post again. The first group is already lazy as I explained in the OP.